# Prove that $nullT^k=nullT$ and $rangeT^k=rangeT$

Tags: linear-algebra

Supppose $T\in\mathcal L \left({V}\right)$ is normal. Prove that

$nullT^k=nullT$ and $rangeT^k=rangeT$

For all positive integers $k$

### My attempt

I know that an operator on an inner product space is called normal if it commutes with its adjoint

I know that $T\in\mathcal L \left({V}\right)$ is normal if $TT^*=T^*T$.

I am not sure where to start here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way without the spectral theorem. (Do I smell a new Linear Algebra book @SheldonAxler ;)?)

It's not hard to show that $\operatorname{null} T \subseteq \operatorname{null} T^k$ and $\operatorname{range} T^k \subseteq \operatorname{range} T$ straight from the definitions. What we want is the reverse inclusions, given that $T$ is normal.

First, we show that $\operatorname{null} T^k \subseteq \operatorname{null} T$ assuming $T$ is normal. We go by induction on $k$. The base case is $k=2$. We use the following standard facts about normal operators. (If you want elaboration on these, please say so -- they can be found in Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right.*)

> **Theorem 1.** If $T$ is normal, then $\|Tv\| = \|T^* v\|$ for all $v \in V$.
>
> **Theorem 2.** $\operatorname{null} (T^*) = (\operatorname{range} T)^\perp$

Base case:

> $v \in \operatorname{null} T^2 \iff 0 = \|T^2 v\| = \|T^* T v\|$ by Theorem 1. This is equivalent to $T^* T v = 0 \iff Tv \in \operatorname{null}(T^*) \iff Tv \in (\operatorname{range} T)^\perp$ by Theorem 2. The statement $Tv \in (\operatorname{range} T)^\perp$ means that $Tv$ is self-orthogonal (being a member of $\operatorname{range} T$) and hence $0$, i.e., $Tv = 0$. Hence $v \in \operatorname{null} T$, and we've shown the base case $\operatorname{null} T^2 = \operatorname{null} T$.

For the inductive step, assume that $\operatorname{null} T^{k-1} = \cdots = \operatorname{null} T^2 = \operatorname{null} T$. Then

> \begin{align*} v \in \operatorname{null} T^k &\iff 0 = T^{k-1} Tv \\  &\iff Tv \in \operatorname{null} T^{k-1} \\   &\iff Tv \in \operatorname{null} T && \text{Induction hypothesis} \\   &\iff T^2 v = 0 \\   &\iff v \in \operatorname{null} T^2 \\   &\iff v \in \operatorname{null} T. && \text{Induction hypothesis}   \end{align*}

This completes the inductive step; hence we've proved

> **Theorem 3.** If $T$ is normal, then $\operatorname{null} T^k = \operatorname{null} T$ for all positive integers $k$.

For the statement about the range, we use our statement about the kernal and Theorem 2 again:

> \begin{align*} \operatorname{range} T^k &= \left( \operatorname{null} (T^k)^*\right)^\perp &&\text{Theorem 2, $(U^\perp)^\perp = U$} \\  &= \left( \operatorname{null} (T)^*\right)^\perp && \text{Theorem 3 applied to $T^*$} \\  &= \operatorname{range} T. && \text{Theorem 2, $(U^\perp)^\perp = U$}  \end{align*}

Comment: spectral theorem hasn't been introduced yet

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Those equalities hold for any diagonalizable operator.

Comment: I also know $||T^{k}(v)||^2$ =0 and $<T^{k}(v).T^{k}(v)>=0>$ for v in nullT^k